# android sound overlap command line ffmpeg not working

Tags: android, audio

I want to mix(not concatenate) 2 audio files in android. For ex : first file has audio and second file has voice. I want to mix these 2 files and generate output file who have music and voice playing simultaneously.

I know about ffmpeg. i have compile ffmpeg using android NDK. but i do not know how to run ffmpeg command using android

other way instead of ffmpeg is also ok.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: What format are the input files in, and what format do you want the output in (encoding and container)?

Comment: I prefer to merge mp3 format files ..

Answer (score 0):

Check out those resources for Audio/Video tasks with FFmpeg for Android:

Tutorial to compile FFmpeg for Android:
http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

FFMpeg API examples:
http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html

Also if you search github for FFmpeg and Android you'll find a lot of resources.

Hope this helps,

Cheers.